# Reading ID3 tags in Xamarin/Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, id3

Is it possible? How easy is it?

I added a reference to TaglibSharp, an ID3 library for C# I've used for a long time in .NET applications, but it isn't detected within the activity/any classes. Taglib is built for (I think) Mono/.NET 3.5, but I'm assuming it needs to be "rebuilt" for Android? (I opened up the library's source and the only options for platform in Visual Studio and Xamarin are variations of Mono and .NET)

If working with Taglib isn't a possibility because it wouldn't end up working on the Android platform, is there another way? I've searched pretty extensively for Xamarin ID3 support and all I've found is [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2341/read-and-write-mp3-tags).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You'll need to build TaglibSharp from source.

Comment: @Jason Hmmm..I imagine I can just grab the full solution from Github and build it with Visual Studio, but don't I need to build it for Xamarin/Android, something different than .NET? I don't have much experience working outside of .NET.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6306735/2246344)?

Comment: @Sam I might be wrong, but is Mediametadataretriever in Mono.Android.Media? I can't seem to find it. If you were referring to the rest of the answers, i.e. reading the data byte-by-byte, I can do that, I'm just hoping to find an easier solution.

Comment: @Wilson It should be there: [Android.Media.MediaMetadataRetriever](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Media.MediaMetadataRetriever%2f*). Can you still not find it?

Comment: @Sam Nope...I feel like I'm completely missing something. In the assembly browser, this is every class and enum starting with 'm' in Android.Media (in Mono.Android): http://i.imgur.com/a01Gj5K.png

Comment: @Sam Ah, my project was set to target Froyo for whatever reason. There it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`Android.Media.MediaMetadataRetriever`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Media.MediaMetadataRetriever%2f%2A) class to read all the information you need.

Here's an example to how to get the title of a file,

```
MediaMetadataRetriever reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

reader.setDataSource("some file path");

String title = reader.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

---

`MediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata()` options,

> - `MetadataKeyAlbum`: The metadata key to retrieve
>     the information about the album title of the data source.
> - `MetadataKeyAlbumartist`: The metadata key to
>     retrieve the information about the performers or artist associated
>     with the data source.
> - `MetadataKeyArtist`: The metadata key to retrieve
>     the information about the artist of the data source.
> - `MetadataKeyAuthor`: The metadata key to retrieve
>     the information about the author of the data source.
> - `MetadataKeyBitrate`: This key retrieves the
>     average bitrate (in bits/sec), if available.
> - `MetadataKeyCdTrackNumber`: The metadata
>     key to retrieve the numberic string describing the order of the audio
>     data source on its original recording.
> - `MetadataKeyCompilation`: The metadata key to
>     retrieve the music album compilation status.
> - `MetadataKeyComposer`: The metadata key to
>     retrieve the information about the composer of the data source.
> - `MetadataKeyDate`: The metadata key to retrieve
>     the date when the data source was created or modified.
> - `MetadataKeyDiscNumber`: The metadata key to
>     retrieve the numeric string that describes which part of a set the
>     audio data source comes from.
> - `MetadataKeyDuration`: The metadata key to
>     retrieve the playback duration of the data source.
> - `MetadataKeyGenre`: The metadata key to retrieve
>     the content type or genre of the data source.
> - `MetadataKeyHasAudio`: If this key exists the
>     media contains audio content.
> - `MetadataKeyHasVideo`: If this key exists the
>     media contains video content.
> - `MetadataKeyMimetype`: The metadata key to
>     retrieve the mime type of the data source.
> - `MetadataKeyNumTracks`: The metadata key to
>     retrieve the number of tracks, such as audio, video, text, in the data
>     source, such as a mp4 or 3gpp file.
> - `MetadataKeyTitle`: The metadata key to retrieve
>     the data source title.
> - `MetadataKeyVideoHeight`: If the media contains
>     video, this key retrieves its height.
> - `MetadataKeyVideoWidth`: If the media contains
>     video, this key retrieves its width.
> - `MetadataKeyWriter`: The metadata key to retrieve
>     the information of the writer (such as lyricist) of the data source.
> - `MetadataKeyYear`: The metadata key to retrieve the year when the data source was created or modified.

<sup>[*Source.*](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Media.MediaMetadataRetriever%2fF)</sup>

Comment: great, thanks for the thorough response. Just one further question, is writing ID3 tags similarly easy, or entirely different?

Comment: @Wilson There's probably a hidden library out there for this, but unfortunately I don't know of anything; which will mean writing the tags manually yourself, byte for byte, it's a bit tricky though. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17890/Do-Anything-With-ID3) should help you out, if you want to do it "manually".