# Android - Add audio detail to mp3 file

Tags: android, mp3

I created an android radio player with recorder. Both of them work very well. The audio is recorded as expected. But now i want to add some detail to this audio(mp3) file, like album-art, artist-name etc. Is there any way to do this. Please ignore my errors and mistakes.

Comment: It's all stored in the **metadata** area of the file (like how additional info is stored in JPEG files).

Comment: how can i access or change it. is it require a plug-in?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306636/read-id3-tags-of-an-mp3-file

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Android port of Lame encoder [Lame encoder](http://lame.sourceforge.net)

Form example [Dialog with ID3 tag edit](https://github.com/onix-adt/Onix-Mp3-Recorder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/onix/recorder/lame/dialog/Id3TagsDialog.java), something like that :

```
    TrackId3Tags  mTrackId3Tags = new TrackId3Tags();

    mTrackId3Tags.setTitle("Title");
    mTrackId3Tags.setArtist("Artist");
```

Comment: Thank for your response. Actually my main problem was the file structure, that I didn't create a structured(valid) mp3 file. I only create a file object & starts putting the stream into that file. But for a valid audio mp3 file there should be file header which contains this metadata & then the actual mp3 stream. My problem is still there because I don't know how to create an empty mp3 file & then place my audio stream there.

Comment: Do you already have mp3 encoded packets? You can pass raw audio data into lame encoder like in project.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference link?

Comment: https://github.com/onix-adt/Onix-Mp3-Recorder/blob/3a4034f5d239f02eb1bf0b24e7bb2c72a01b3521/app/src/main/java/com/onix/recorder/lame/core/LameCore.java take a look at private native static int lameEncode(short[] buffer_l, short[] buffer_r, int samples, byte[] mp3buf); method. buffer_l and buffer_r is a raw data for left and right channel. Right now in project using data from mic, but you can replace it with you own data.