# What is the best method to get image from audiofile?

Tags: android, audio

What I need is to retrieve image embedded in audiofile, I have tried ffmpegmediametadataretriever (too large, increased size of my app for additional 20mb, not the best solution), mediametadataretriever (on some devices it works just fine, but on the other it doesn't and makes it impossible for my app to start). I need lightweight, working on all devices solution.What is the best solution here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read ID3 Tags of an MP3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306636/read-id3-tags-of-an-mp3-file)

Comment: I am looking for the best method, I have written that I know how to make it work but to my mind there should be a better way.

Comment: to search you need criteria ... what metadata do your audio files have to search by ?  ... also update your question to specify what image you need ... album cover ? semantic match ? ... might help if you first identify metadata providers then see what they ask for regarding search criteria

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this

[How can I display Album Art using MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573972/how-can-i-display-album-art-using-mediastore-audio-albums-album-art)